# How can I stack multiple ternary plots on top of each other in 3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have data to make multiple ternary plots, each having 3 points on it.

Is it possible to stack those ternary plots in 3D on top of each other? Then, is it possible to connect the points of the same color in each ternary plot with each other in 3D to see how, for example, the blue point evolves as you move in 3D.

Here is an example to make 2 ternary plots.

```
vec1 = {{{0.3, 0.4, 0.3}}, {{0.6, 0.3, 0.1}}, {{0.25, 0.25, 0.5}}}; 
vec2 = {{{0.25, 0.3, 0.45}}, {{0.5, 0.15, 0.35}}, {{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}}}; 
TernaryListPlot[{vec1[[1]], vec1[[2]], vec1[[3]]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Magenta}, FrameLabel -> {"A", "B", "C"}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.04]]
TernaryListPlot[{vec2[[1]], vec2[[2]], vec2[[3]]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Magenta}, FrameLabel -> {"A", "B", "C"}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.04]]
```

Can I stack these two and connect vec1[[1]] to vec2[[1]], vec1[[2]] to vec2[[2]] etc using a line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this result?

**Edit**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ternary[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] := {p1 + 1/2 p2, Sqrt[3]/2 p2};

vec1 = {{{0.3, 0.4, 0.3}}, {{0.6, 0.3, 0.1}}, {{0.25, 0.25, 0.5}}};
vec2 = {{{0.25, 0.3, 0.45}}, {{0.5, 0.15, 0.35}}, {{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}}};

pts1 = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ ternary /@ Flatten[vec1, 1];
pts2 = PadRight[#, 3, 1] & /@ ternary /@ Flatten[vec2, 1];
plane1 = 
  Polygon[PadRight[#, 3] & /@ 
    ternary /@ {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];
plane2 = 
  Polygon[PadRight[#, 3, 1] & /@ 
    ternary /@ {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}];

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.2], plane1, 
   plane2}, {MapThread[{#3, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[#1], 
      Point[#2], Arrow[{#1, #2}]} &, {pts1, 
     pts2, {Blue, Red, Magenta}}]}}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
vec1 = {{{0.3, 0.4, 0.3}}, {{0.6, 0.3, 0.1}}, {{0.25, 0.25, 0.5}}};
vec2 = {{{0.25, 0.3, 0.45}}, {{0.5, 0.15, 0.35}}, {{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}}};
plane = ContourPlot3D[x + y + z == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
    Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {White, Opacity[0.8]}];
points1 = ListPointPlot3D[vec1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Magenta}];
points2 = ListPointPlot3D[vec2, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Magenta}];
arrows = 
  Graphics3D[Arrow /@ Thread@{Flatten[vec1, 1], Flatten[vec2, 1]}];
Show[plane, points1, points2, arrows, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the magnitude of each vector that produces a point is exactly 1, so in a way, each of the points show percentages of what I call A,B, and C in the ternary plots. That is why I need them to stay in a ternary plot, and have them stacked with increasing z-direction. Even if adding arrows is not doable, it would still be helpful to simply have the ternary plots stacked on top of each other with some fixed space in between each consecutive one.

Comment: @juv95  I have updated the answer,does it satisfy the request?

Answer (score 3):

Pre-process input data to add z-coordinates and re-group:

```
zlevels = {1, 5};

vecs = Transpose @ MapApply[Map[Append[#]] @ Apply[Join][#2]&][
   Transpose @ {zlevels, {vec1, vec2}}]
```

> ```
>  {{{0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 1}, {0.25, 0.3, 0.45, 5}},  
>   {{0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 1}, {0.5, 0.15, 0.35, 5}},  
>   {{0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 5}}}
> ```

Use `vecs` with `` Charting`TernaryListPlot3D ``:

```
Charting`TernaryListPlot3D[vecs,
 "PlotBaseStyle" -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[9]],
 PlotRange -> {-3, 9}, FaceGrids -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[], EdgeForm[]]]
```

[image]

Post-process to add arrows:

```
ReplaceAll[Point[x_] :> {Point[x], Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[x]}] @ %
```

[image]

If needed, add ternary clip-planes at desired z-levels:

```
Show[%,
 MapThread[
   Charting`TernaryListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0, #}, {0, 0, 1, #}, {0, 1,  0, #}}, 
     "PlotBaseStyle" -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[0]], 
     Ticks -> None, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Directive[Opacity[.1], #2]], 
       EdgeForm[]]] &][{zlevels, {Red, Green}}], 
 BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]